# Resize border NOT window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="IPCapture.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:IPCapture"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="IPCapture_GUI" Opacity="0.95" Background="Transparent" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold" FontStretch="UltraExpanded" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" BorderThickness="0"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Cursor="Arrow" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown" Topmost="True" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
    <Window.OpacityMask>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#B2420000" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Window.OpacityMask>
    <Border CornerRadius="5" Background="#FFC20C0C" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
        <Grid x:Name="GridMain" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Keys" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Values" Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Opacity="0.6" BlurRadius="1"/>
        </Border.Effect>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

I followed many tutorials on how to achieve the GUI I wanted and I finally succeeded! However, it does not seem to provide the functionality that I need. I want to:

- **Resize** the **width** of the GUI

A visualisation of my problem:

[image: WPF]

The large faded blue area is my `Window` and the small GUI in the top-left corner of that is my actual widget.
*(That is enclosed in the `Border`)*

As you can see from my code, I have set `ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"` on the `Window`. I am able to resize the window perfectly fine **BUT** resizing it does not resize my actual GUI.
*(Because of how my XAML is laid out)*

So, for this reason, I want to somehow allow resize on the width of the border instead of the `Window`.

Additions: *(if possible)*

- Is it possible to remove that small black toolbar that's centered on the top of the `Window`?
- I am also confused as to why, because I have set `Height` and `Width` of the `Window` to `Auto`, is it so large? Shouldn't it only expand as large as it's content?

Comment: What does your `OnLoad` code do? A quick copy/paste of your code to my environment, with a min height/width given to your grid, gives me just the floating red box, with no transparent overlay over the rest of the screen. I am using VS 2010 though, and Windows 7. If I change the bg color from Transparent to Blue, I can see the full window with the resize grip, or removing the `HorizontalAlignment/VerticalAlignment` makes the Border size match the window size.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take it one at a time:

- The resize issue is because of `HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"` you've set on the `Grid` and the `Border`. It means the element will measure its minimum required width & height and align to the top left. If you remove this, the element will (assuming there are no other layout issues) resize to contain the entire window.
- Setting `Auto` for `Width` and `Height` (which is the default, by the way) behaves differently on a window - it tells the OS - not WPF - to determine the initial size (using an undisclosed algorithm, so don't rely on it). If you want WPF to resize the window to the minimum required by its content, set `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`.
- The small black toolbar is a new VS 2015 feature and only appears during debugging. You can turn it off in the Live Visual Tree panel in VS.

Bonus tips:

- I strongly discourage you from applying an `Effect` on the entire visual tree. It's a huge performance hit. You should look into using `SystemDropShadowChrome`.
- Same goes for `OpacityMask`. Just use a uniform `Opacity` unless you really need that gradient... Even then you may be better off using a uniform opacity and a gradient brush as the background.

Comment: 2/3 man! My only issue is that I thought when I would resize the window, that (due to all `Height` and `Width`'s set to `Auto`), the `Width` of the `Grid` would resize as well. I can see this is not working as in my 2nd column, contents in the grid rows are set to `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` and on resize, they stay where they are. Would this have caused another issue? Also, really appreaciative of all the tips, thank you :)

Comment: If I remove the the alignment of the labels within the grid and expand the width, the grid still does not seem to respond by staying the same width

Comment: @wmash Get rid of `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` from everywhere. You only want those properties if you want to dock a control to the side of something, or to force the control to stretch the full size in panels that don't normally manipulate the child sizes, like `Canvas`.

Comment: @Rachel `HorizontalAlignment` or `VerticalAlignment` are not set anywhere on anything

Comment: @wmash Hrm I guess I'm not sure I understand what your ultimate desired behavior is. Do you always want your Grid to fill the entire application window, or do you want to allow the user to resize the window, while the Grid maintains a fixed height/width?

Comment: @Rachel The Grid will fill the entire window. The Height of the window is fixed and the width can be resized by the user. For example, when the app loads, all rows which hold data are then added into the Grid. At the end of this, I am fixing the height of the window so it cannot be resized. The width, however, can be manually resized. On width resize, the width of the Grid will resize as well (so filling 100% width of the window all the time). The labels in the 2nd column of the Grid, has there `HorizontalAlignment` set to `Right`. If this is still possible, this would be ideal